# How To Stop at the End of a Function (Without Exiting it) In GDB?

Tags: gdb

Please consider the following Code:

```
main()
{
    ....
    retval = func();
}
```

Suppose I put a breakpoint on a given function:

```
gdb$ b func
```

Now, this breakpoint gets hit & I do 'finish' in function func():

```
gdb$ fin
```

My Problem is:

Doing 'finish' brings me back to main(), here:

```
retval = func();
```

I want to stop at the END of func() without Exiting func().

Can somebody please suggest some generic way (independent of the no. of lines of code in func()) to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Set a break point on last line of `func()`?  Not sure it that qualifies as independent of number of lines.

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to make an automated solution through .gdbinit - to work for any number of functions. Can't put breakpoints on last line.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do it.  Compilers generally don't emit the needed bit of debuginfo (there's a GCC bug open about this); and even if they did, gdb wouldn't read it; and even if it did it would need new syntax for you to be able to specify it as a breakpoint location.

I don't remember offhand if there is a gdb bug for this, but there ought to be.

Comment: There is *simple* way to do this, but one can always use `disas` and set a breakpoint on the `ret` instruction.

Comment: I suppose it could even be automated.  However, this is not likely to get the result he likes, since the ret will be after the epilogue, and so most variables will be out of scope.  I think it's more useful to users for the breakpoint to be set after the return value is computed but before the epilogue.  Insofar as that can be done.

Answer (score -1):

You can type two commands 's' and 'finish'.

`s      - step in to func() function`

`finish - finish function and go back to the outside func(). In this case to the main()`